# Linux bridge for virtual machines not forwarding IP packets (but is forwarding ARP)

Tags: linux, bridge

Kernel: 5.5.8-arch1-1

I am trying to get virtual networking working using a bridge attached to my physical interface. This is a typical setup, I'm not even trying to do anything *weird*.

- Bridge: `br0`
- Phys interface: `enp6s0f0`

The problem is that Linux isn't forwarding any IP traffic out the physical interface. It's forwarding *ARP traffic* both ways since ARP resolution works, but no IP traffic gets *sent out of enp6s0f0*.

Things I've tried:

- adding `enp6s0f1` to the bridge, giving `enp7s0f0` to the VM, and using a cable to link `enp7s0f0` to `enp6s0f1`

  - same result (ARP traffic forwarded, IP traffic not)
- stopping docker and flushing all tables

  - no change
- disabling rp_filter

  - no change
- using the onboard NIC

  - no change (this was actually the initial setup and I dropped this quad-port card in to see if was the onboard NIC causing a problem)
- pinging the VM from another machine

  - I could see the echo-request come *in* and I could see it on `br0` but it was not forwarded to the VM port (either the vnet port or `enp6s0f1`)
- enabling STP on the bridge (it was initially disabled)

  - no change

```
○ → ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp6s0f0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:10:18:85:1c:c0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::210:18ff:fe85:1cc0/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp6s0f1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:10:18:85:1c:c2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: enp7s0f0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:10:18:85:1c:c4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: enp7s0f1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:10:18:85:1c:c6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: enp9s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b4:2e:99:a6:22:f9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
7: wlp8s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:71:90:4e:e9:77 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
8: br-183e1a17d7f6: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:ba:03:e1:9d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.18.0.1/16 brd 172.18.255.255 scope global br-183e1a17d7f6
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
9: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:02:61:00:66 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
10: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:10:18:85:1c:c0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.205/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute br0
       valid_lft 9730sec preferred_lft 7930sec
    inet6 fe80::210:18ff:fe85:1cc0/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
11: vnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master br0 state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:54:00:be:eb:3e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:febe:eb3e/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

○ → brctl showstp br0
br0
 bridge id      8000.001018851cc0
 designated root    1000.44e4d9d88a00
 root port         1            path cost          4
 max age          19.99         bridge max age        19.99
 hello time        1.99         bridge hello time      1.99
 forward delay        14.99         bridge forward delay      14.99
 ageing time         299.99
 hello timer           0.00         tcn timer          0.00
 topology change timer     0.00         gc timer          25.78
 flags          


enp6s0f0 (1)
 port id        8001            state            forwarding
 designated root    1000.44e4d9d88a00   path cost          4
 designated bridge  1000.44e4d9d88a00   message age timer     19.21
 designated port    800d            forward delay timer    0.00
 designated cost       0            hold timer         0.00
 flags          

vnet0 (2)
 port id        8002            state            forwarding
 designated root    1000.44e4d9d88a00   path cost        100
 designated bridge  8000.001018851cc0   message age timer      0.00
 designated port    8002            forward delay timer    0.00
 designated cost       4            hold timer         0.22
 flags          

○ → bridge -d link show
2: enp6s0f0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 master br0 state forwarding priority 32 cost 4 
    hairpin off guard off root_block off fastleave off learning on flood on mcast_flood on mcast_to_unicast off neigh_suppress off vlan_tunnel off isolated off enp6s0f0
8: br-183e1a17d7f6: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 master br-183e1a17d7f6 br-183e1a17d7f6
9: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 master docker0 docker0
10: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 master br0 br0
11: vnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 master br0 state forwarding priority 32 cost 100 
    hairpin off guard off root_block off fastleave off learning on flood on mcast_flood on mcast_to_unicast off neigh_suppress off vlan_tunnel off isolated off vnet0

○ → sysctl net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 1

○ → sysctl net.ipv4.conf.br0.forwarding
net.ipv4.conf.br0.forwarding = 1
```

Comment: Link `enp7s0f0` to the bridge as well

Comment: @maze then I wouldn't be testing the scenario I was experimenting with: VM → enp7s0f0 → cable → enp6s0f1 (on br0 bridge). This was solely done to eliminate some weird interaction with the vnet interface on the bridge.

Comment: Didn't know that this is a fixed setup. I had a similar issue a while ago but it was the result of a wrong setup. Did you think of adding the right route via br0 ?

Comment: Does the virtual host allow mac address spoofing? This needs to be enabled on Hyper-V for virtual routers since a single MAC is sent all sorts of dest IPs.

Comment: From @phbits Not enough rep to comment, does the virtual host allow mac address spoofing? This needs to be enabled on Hyper-V for virtual routers since a single MAC is sent all sorts of dest IPs.

Comment: @maze there is no "route" to add via br0 since this is a layer 2 bridge, not a layer 3 router

Comment: @phbits the virtual host is physical. Even if it was a virtual host under Hyper-V, it will still see the packets leave the "physical" interface on the virtual host, they just wouldn't be passed on by the Hyper-V bridge. And ARP wouldn't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Docker [loads](https://github.com/moby/libnetwork/blob/4e15af8e7fc6ac4090b2c3aa093e91460fba8e31/drivers/bridge/bridge.go#L357) the [`br_netfilter`](http://ebtables.netfilter.org/documentation/bridge-nf.html) module (to get the *sysctl* property `net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables=1`) when it uses iptables. This makes *bridged* frames (Ethernet, layer 2) subject to *iptables* filtering (IP, layer 3):

> What's bridge-netfilter?
>
> Since Linux kernel 3.18-rc1, you have to modprobe br_netfilter to
> enable bridge-netfilter.
>
> The bridge-netfilter code enables the following functionality:
>
> **{Ip,Ip6,Arp}tables can filter bridged IPv4/IPv6/ARP packets**, even when encapsulated in an 802.1Q VLAN or PPPoE header. This enables the
> functionality of a stateful transparent firewall.
> All filtering, logging and NAT features of the 3 tools can therefore be used on bridged frames.
> Combined with ebtables, the bridge-nf code therefore makes Linux a very powerful transparent firewall.
> This enables, f.e., the creation of a transparent masquerading machine (i.e. all local hosts think they are directly connected to the
> Internet).
> **Letting {ip,ip6,arp}tables see bridged traffic can be disabled or enabled using the appropriate proc entries**, located in
> `/proc/sys/net/bridge/`:

> - `bridge-nf-call-arptables`
> - `bridge-nf-call-iptables`
> - `bridge-nf-call-ip6tables`

There is documentation explaining side effects caused by this module. Those side effects are *intended* when using it for bridge transparent firewalling. Also, the *iptables* `physdev` (which loads `br_netfilter` when itself loaded) match cannot work properly without it (it simply won't match anymore). It's also explained how to prevent its effects, especially in [chapter 7](http://ebtables.netfilter.org/br_fw_ia/br_fw_ia.html#section7):

> Because of the br-nf code, there are 2 ways a frame/packet can pass
> through the 3 given iptables chains. **The first way is when the frame
> is bridged, so the iptables chains are called by the bridge code**. The
> second way is when the packet is routed.

Rather than disabling the call to *iptables* by `br_netfilter`'s code like this:

```
sysctl -w net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables=0
```

one should adapt *iptables* rules wherever they are (including whatever the network namespace) as explained in chapter 7 to avoid side effets, by adding for example accept rules in the FORWARD chain intended not for routing but for bridging. Simply disabling it to fix one problem will disrupt the applications that depend on it, starting with Docker's internal container isolation.

Until recently [in](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/commit/?id=ff6d090d0db41425aef0cfe5dc58bb3cc12514a2) [kernel 5.3](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/commit/?id=22567590b2e634247931b3d2351384ba45720ebe) this module was not namespace-aware and having it loaded suddenly enabled it on all network namespaces causing all kind of troubles when unexpected. It's also since then that it's possible to enable it per bridge (`ip link set dev BRIDGE type bridge nf_call_iptables 1`) rather than per namespace.

Once tools (Docker...) and kernel (>= 5.3) follow evolution, simply having it enabled in select network namespaces and bridges should suffice, but today probably not. Also note that [kernel 5.3](https://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_5.3#Networking) also inherited native bridge stateful firewalling, usable by *nftables*, which is a step to obsolete the use of this module (once direct encapsulation/decapsulation support in bridge for VLAN and PPPoE are available):

> Netfilter
>
> Add native connection tracking support for the bridge. Before this
> patchset, only chance for people to do stateful filtering is to use
> the br_netfilter emulation layer, this is a step forward to deprecate
> it

Comment: FWIW, a change in the 19.03 version of docker is that it now sets the policy on the FORWARD chain to DROP when it loads.

Comment: When you say "disabling on iptables this module like this" I guess there should be value 0, not 1: `sysctl -w net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables=0`