# Linux bridge does not forward packets to TAP interface

Tags: networking, kvm, bridge, container, tap

I have the following scenario where I run a Docker container which has configured inside of it a Linux bridge `br0` and attached to it I have the main interface `eth0` of the container and a TAP interface `tap0`. This last is connected to a QEMU guest machine running into the container.

The Docker container runs on a Kubernetes cluster with Calico as CNI.

The situation I have is that when I `ping` the IP of the container (which is assigned to the TAP interface) then I get no response.

I have then started to debug with the old mate `tcpdump` and I have found out that the packet arrives correctly to the `eth0` of the container, they go to the bridge `br0`  but they do not arrive to the TAP interface `tap0`. For some unknown reasons, the packets are discarded.

Do you have any idea?

I have tried to disable the rf filter of the bridge but did not get to anything.

Comment: Would you be using NetworkPolicies, maybe?! Nothing out of the ordinary with your other containers?

Comment: The mere fact of running Docker usually activates the infamous br_netfilter module which interferes with bridging. I don't know for k8s. Check these Q/A (where I made answers about this interference): https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/572022/linux-bridge-for-virtual-machines-not-forwarding-ip-packets-but-is-forwarding-a/572086#572086, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/572022/linux-bridge-for-virtual-machines-not-forwarding-ip-packets-but-is-forwarding-a/572086#572086 , or on SF: https://serverfault.com/questions/963759/docker-breaks-libvirt-bridge-network/964491#964491

Comment: No SYN no network policies.

Comment: @A.B I would need to double check but I've already run sysctl to disable iptables inside the container but I did not get the result wanted, maybe I've should run inside the guest QEMU

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the issue.

The reason was that the routes stolen to the container were not pushed into the guest OS.

Comment: could you please elaborate?