# Docker installation causes network loss

Tags: networking, fedora, docker

I have trying to install DOCKER in my Fedora 35 but when I install it I lost the internet connection in my machine.

`$ sudo dnf install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io`

I try to traceroute but the response is ****. Access to internet doesn't works.

When I erase the docker rpm files and reboot the system the network is working again.

Regards

Comment: This is NOT a recommendation, but I'm wondering if you installed [`docker` from the docker repo](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/fedora/) if it might work for you.

Comment: Docker disrupts network settings because of the br_netfilter module and the forward drop policy, especially firewalls. See a few Q/A where I made answers about this on UL SE and SF: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/572022/linux-bridge-for-virtual-machines-not-forwarding-ip-packets-but-is-forwarding-a , https://serverfault.com/questions/963759/docker-breaks-libvirt-bridge-network . If you can't debug with remote console access, it looks hard to figure out what's your precise problem. It could also be an IP address conflict with your specific LAN or many other possibilities.

Comment: Following up on @rickhg12hs's question for the benefit of future people who google brings here like it did me: don't bother reinstalling from the docker repo. That's how I installed it to begin with, and it permanently knocked out my laptop's networking. Seeing has how I need the software I run in docker, and I need it to be available on the network.... I have absolutely no idea what I'm going to do now. Any way you slice it, Debian12 and Docker appears to be a 100% unusable setup if you need your computer to be available on the network. (Obviously, from the lack of an answer in almost 2 yrs.)